# html page is getting a large vertical scroll for less content

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a page with bootstarp-vue table. Table has a stick header and scroll. Height of the table is 65vh.
So there's a container div with height 65vh and there's a table inside it. container scrolls.

I have a lot of rows in the table that extend beyond the container of the table.

Everything's fine. I get a nice scroll for the container of the table with header of the table fixed at the top.

But, the page is getting a vertical scroll. The table is only half of the page and there's no content after the table. But I still see a large vertical scroll.

Comment: Show us some code or the final result in html

Comment: How are we supposed to know what's causing the vertical scroll if we can't inspect it? Please provide a *runnable* [mcve]. Without one it is technically impossible for anyone to help you.